# Парсинг HTML C++

Tags: html, c++, dom, poco

Использую библиотеку Poco для парсинга HTML странички, но возникла проблема. Используя Poco::XML::DOMParser, выскакивает exception "Duplicate attribute in line 35 column 44". Сразу скажу, что HTML я не смогу поменять или убрать какой-то дублированный элемент. Может, есть какой то флаг по типу XML_NOERR? Но что то похожее в Poco я не нашел

Comment: А у POCO нет парсера именно HTML? А то XML имеет более строгий синтаксис, чем HTML :)

Comment: К сожалению не нашел :c

Comment: html нельзя парсить посредством XML парсера. Используйте парсер HTML, gumbo например.

Comment: Благодарю! Попробую, отпишу.